# Multitasking solutions to (not-rooted) Android OS and Apps out there?

Tags: applications, stock-android, user-interface, multitasking, multi-window

For here i mean multitasking *visually*, which means the ability to see more than one Apps at a time.

Other than Samsung's [Multi Window](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/supportOwnersHowToGuidePopup.do?howto_guide_seq=10096&prd_ia_cd=N0000003&map_seq=120424), [Popup Play](http://www.samsung.com/global/galaxys3/popupplay.html) (or by the [Stick It!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myboyfriendisageek.stickit) app), [Pen Window](http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/note3tutorial/note3/tutorial/pen_window_index.html), or the LG's [QSlide](http://www.androidcentral.com/qslide-lg-g2-quick-way-access-frequently-used-tools), [Slide Aside](http://www.androidcentral.com/slide-aside-lg-s-app-switching-feature-g2), and [Dual Window](http://www.lg.com/us/mobile-phones/gflex/experience.jsp), are there any other multitasking solutions else from the major vendors out there?

I would only consider reliable solutions, which means the original untwisted rom (i know original doesn't necessarily means reliable, but as least i got warranty), or by certain android apps which requires no-rooting, or any other solutions with clear lines of instructions or codes.

Comment: If you don't want to display all your existing apps next to each other, there's that "floating" API used by [several specific apps](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=floating) (I'm sure not all of the ~4,500 apps in that list are matches, but you'll get the idea). For one true example, take a look at [Floating Browser](http://www.appbrain.com/app/floating-browser/gpc.myweb.hinet.net.PopupWeb).

Comment: Just FYI. I have bought S5 and I am happy with its Multi-Window function. Hope I will have chance to write a few apps to make use of this feature.